# Adding event listeners to hundreds of google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using google maps javascript api v3.  I have approx 500 markers set on the map.  When I'm using the map on a mobile device there is significant lag when moving the map around and clicking on markers.  I believe this lag is caused by having 500 event listeners for the 500 markers.

I'd like to bind 1 event listener to the map container that can handle all map marker clicks, like this(using jquery):

`$('#map').on('click', 'marker', function(event) {`

```
    alert('marker clicked: ' + marker.uniqueInfo);
});
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: not really directly helpful to the question, but I'd like to know what on earth you could possibly need 500 markers on a mobile app map for..I don't know what your app is but surely 500 markers on a little phone screen can't be useful to anyone.. my first thought would be to rethink your design to have less markers on your map at a time.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but how do expect a user to use 500 markers on a mobile device?  Why not combine those that are close to one another into a group marker to help simplify the interface?  I don't think I could handle more than 25 markers on my phone with my fat fingers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: An alternative, depending on your application, can be a heat map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the event handler is attached is only binding one listener to one element (`#map`). See the jQuery documentation for more on how `.on()` works: http://api.jquery.com/on/. Basically any and all clicks to the markers bubble up to the element with ID of `map`.

To accomplish the `.on()` technique, try utilizing the `event` object argument to find the targeted marker: `event.target`.

```
$('#map').on('click', 'marker', function(event) {
    var marker = getMarker(event.target);
    alert('marker clicked: ' + marker.uniqueInfo);
});
```

Here, I'm assuming there is some utility `getMarker` that will return a Google Maps marker instance for the given HTML element.

Be aware that there may be some performance gains from binding the event this way, but it still may not be as fast as you would like simply due to the sheer volume of markers on the map.

Comment: no..he is saying he currently has ~500 event listeners bound to ~500 elements, and he wants a solution involving binding an event to a single parent element, and gave that pseudocode as an example and wants someone to fill in the blanks for `marker.uniqueInfo`

Comment: The code I showed is what I'd like to have.  The normal way to add listeners to markers on a google map is to loop through all markers and add a listener to each one.

Comment: Yeah, read the section on "direct and delegated" events. Basically you want to do a delegated event.  But I agree..doing this may help a little but most of the lag is coming from all the markers to begin with..

Comment: I can't really get this to work.  The markers are added dynamically using the maps api and I can't reference them in the dom.  I put 'marker' in the .on() event because I didn't know what else to do.

Comment: Hi. This answer is not correct for Google Map markers, since the markers are not DOM elements and only exist inside the Google Map.

Answer (score 0):

This is only 1 event listener (so I believe) and acts on bubbled or propagated events, using [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in delegated mode, no idea what the performance difference would be like on your device.

HTML

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="marker">1</div>
    <div class="marker">2</div>
    <div class="marker">3</div>
    <div class="marker">4</div>
    <div class="marker">5</div>
    <div class="marker">6</div>
    <div class="marker">7</div>
    <div class="marker">8</div>
    <div class="marker">9</div>
</div>
```

Javascipt

```
$(document).on('click', '#map .marker', function (event) {
    alert('marker clicked: ' + event.target.textContent);
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/tzuKM/)